# 25 second delay: "No skeleton to export"

Tags: debian, gnome, logs, d-bus, delay

Stuck for quite a while with the problem that launching GNOME apps causes a delay of exactly 25 seconds. I hope someone can read this syslog excerpt better than I can; what a "background monitor", "secret proxy", and "skeleton to export" are is a total mystery to me.

Syslog transcript (`rtkit-daemon` entries excised):

```
2023-12-01T16:55:43.335760-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop' requested by ':1.1041' (uid=1000 pid=1410414 comm="evince ibook.pdf")
2023-12-01T16:55:43.344016-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.Documents' requested by ':1.1042' (uid=1000 pid=1410419 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal")
2023-12-01T16:55:43.344099-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Documents'
2023-12-01T16:55:43.345334-08:00 dowland org.freedesktop.portal.Documents[1410430]: fusermount3: failed to access mountpoint /run/user/1000/doc: Permission denied
2023-12-01T16:55:43.345466-08:00 dowland org.freedesktop.portal.Documents[1410424]: error: fuse init failed: Can't mount path /run/user/1000/doc
2023-12-01T16:55:43.360001-08:00 dowland xdg-desktop-por[1410419]: value "((GDBusConnectionFlags) G_DBUS_CONNECTION_FLAGS_AUTHENTICATION_CLIENT | G_DBUS_CONNECTION_FLAGS_MESSAGE_BUS_CONNECTION | 64)" of type 'GDBusConnectionFlags' is invalid or out of range for property 'flags' of type 'GDBusConnectionFlags'
2023-12-01T16:55:43.360077-08:00 dowland xdg-desktop-por[1410419]: Failed to create background monitor: The connection is closed
2023-12-01T16:55:43.360138-08:00 dowland xdg-desktop-por[1410419]: No skeleton to export
2023-12-01T16:55:43.361944-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.secrets' requested by ':1.1042' (uid=1000 pid=1410419 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal")
2023-12-01T16:55:43.364847-08:00 dowland gnome-keyring-d[1281]: The Secret Service was already initialized
2023-12-01T16:55:43.366081-08:00 dowland org.freedesktop.secrets[1410435]: discover_other_daemon: 1
2023-12-01T16:56:08.387485-08:00 dowland xdg-desktop-por[1410419]: Failed to create secret proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.secrets: Timeout was reached
2023-12-01T16:56:08.387739-08:00 dowland xdg-desktop-por[1410419]: No skeleton to export
2023-12-01T16:56:08.389574-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop'
2023-12-01T16:56:08.427842-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Activating service name='org.gnome.evince.Daemon' requested by ':1.1041' (uid=1000 pid=1410414 comm="evince ibook.pdf")
2023-12-01T16:56:08.430806-08:00 dowland dbus-daemon[209261]: [session uid=1000 pid=209259] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evince.Daemon'
```

Software versions (Debian unstable, just updated):

```
dbus-daemon                               1.14.10-1~deb12u1
gnome-keyring                             42.1-1+b2
xdg-desktop-portal                        1.16.0-2
xdg-desktop-portal-gnome                  43.1-2
xdg-desktop-portal-gtk                    1.14.1-1
xdg-utils                                 1.1.3-4.1
```

I have no idea what `/run/user/1000/doc` is supposed to be, but it's already mounted:

```
portal on /run/user/1000/doc type fuse.portal (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had exactly the same issue with Manjaro after the last updates (2023-11-28 and 2023-12-1).

I copied the `/usr/share/xdg-desktop-portal/gtk-portals.conf` file to `~/.config` and renamed it into `xfce-portals.conf`.

You need to replace the "xfce" for the name of your desktop environment, in all lowercase. See `man portals.conf`

You may need to change the content of the file to use gnome, perhaps. See my post on that subject: [Manjaro Update 2023-12-01 and the XFCE Desktop](https://www.heiko-sieger.info/manjaro-update-2023-12-01-and-the-xfce-desktop/)

Comment: OK. I am using i3 and it is taking a lot of reading to understand whether I want to name GNOME, GTK, or i3 for the portal, and how to confirm that the new config file is working. Nonetheless, you have put me on the road to the solution, so thank you!